# Input Python 3 bytes to C char* via SWIG

Tags: c, python-3.x, swig

Im trying to create a wrapper around SWT algorythm written on C.
I found [this post](https://zablo.net/blog/post/stroke-width-transform-swt-python) and code from there is perfectly working in python 2.7, but when I am trying to run it from python 3, error emerges:
`in method 'swt', argument 1 of type 'char *'`.

As far as I know, it is because `open(img_filename, 'rb').read()` in python 2.7 returns `string` type, but in python 3 it is a `bytes` type.

I tried to modify `ccvwrapper.i` with the code below but without success

```
%typemap(in) char, int, int, int {
     $1 = PyBytes_AS_STRING($1);
}
```

Functions header:
`int* swt(char *bytes, int array_length, int width, int height);`

How I can pass python3 `bytes` to that function via SWIG?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using multi-argument typemaps wrong.  Multi-argument typemaps have to have concrete parameter names.  Otherwise they'd match too greedily in situations where this is not desired.  To get the bytes and the length of the buffer from Python use `PyBytes_AsStringAndSize`.

**`test.i`**

```
%module example
%{
int* swt(char *bytes, int array_length, int width, int height) {
    printf("bytes = %s\narray_length = %d\nwidth = %d\nheight = %d\n",
           bytes, array_length, width, height);
    return NULL;
}
%}

%typemap(in) (char *bytes, int array_length) {
    Py_ssize_t len;
    PyBytes_AsStringAndSize($input, &$1, &len);
    $2 = (int)len;
}

int* swt(char *bytes, int array_length, int width, int height);
```

**`test.py`**

```python
from example import *
swt(b"Hello World!", 100, 50)
```

Example invocation:

```
$ swig -python -py3 test.i
$ clang -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -I /usr/include/python3.6/ -fPIC -shared test_wrap.c -o _example.so -lpython3.6m
$ python3 test.py 
bytes = Hello World!
array_length = 12
width = 100
height = 50
```

Answer (score 4):

```
%module example
%begin %{
#define SWIG_PYTHON_STRICT_BYTE_CHAR
%}
int* swt(char *bytes, int array_length, int width, int height);
```

Comment: Nice one! This is much easier than custom input typemap.